# Android Deleted Sample Projects

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, sample

I created one of the sample projects that come with the android sdk.  When I was done using it I deleted the project and checked "Delete contents from disk".  Now when I try to create a new android project I can no longer recreate the same sample project.

Is there any way to get the sample project back without downloading the entire sdk again?

Comment: I want the project from the same sdk version.  Adding the project from a different version is not an option.

Comment: Did you get some sort of error when trying to create that sample?

Comment: Did you try to run Eclipse with clean parameter? (in the console: eclipse -clean )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about these? You should be able to download them again from [HERE](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample)

If you are still having trouble you may find some help on this [page](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html)

Check the location on your harddrive that is mentioned on the above page and make sure the app/folder is completely gone.

From the above site:

"For example, if you are developing in Eclipse with the ADT Plugin, you can create a project for the "API Demos" sample app by starting a new Android Project, selecting "Create project from existing source", and then browsing to the `<sdk>/samples/android-<level>/ApiDemos` directory"

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to downloas the complete sdk again. The samples are in their own package for each Android level. See http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html for details.